# Can I get inline template as string in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

### Motivation

The inline template in Sinatra is very convenient (for me).

If it is possible to extract there contents as string,
more applications can be expected.

### Example

showing my intention in this code

```
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/json"
require "yaml"

get "/" do
  content_type :json
  data = YAML.load inline_template_as_raw_string(:my_yaml)
  json data
end

__END__
@@my_yaml
foo:
  bar: baz

@@my_something
hello
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinatra stores the raw loaded templates in a settings variables called `templates`. You can access them as follows:

```
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/json"
require "yaml"

get "/" do
  content_type :json
  data = YAML.load settings.templates[:my_yaml][0]
  json data
end

__END__
@@my_yaml
foo:
  bar: baz

@@my_something
hello
```

`settings.templates` contains a Hash with the template names as keys and an array containing the raw template and the line number where it was defined.